# (char**)0 in C ++

Tags: c++, pvm

in PVM , there is a function call `PVM_SPAWN`, the head of this function is :

> pvm_spawn( char *task, char **argv, int flag, char *where, int ntask,
>   int *tids )

when the function is called, the second argument `char** argv` was passing as `(char**)0`

what `(char**)0` means? is it a null pointer or a pointer which point to address 0 ??

Comment: it is a pointer to pointer to char, with NULL value

Comment: Are you familiar with the special meaning a literal `0` has regarding a pointer value? [Perhaps this will clarify it](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/NULL).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C++ 0 and NULL are interchangeable and the value 0 is compatible with all pointers (so there is actually no need to cast it to `char **`)

Answer (score 0):

In C++ 0 is the [null pointer constant](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Null-Pointer-Constant.html) and is guaranteed not to point to any object. You can use it instead of `NULL` if you wish.